# How to get bluetooth headphones working in Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, bluetooth, dongle

I spent several days on this but still no luck. Basically I have Plantronics BackBeat Pro and I also have CSR8510 A10 bluetooth dongle. When I put the dongle into a USB port, Windows installed some generic drivers. It didn't work. Then I installed CSR Bluecore Radio drivers, but still the same result.

I put the headphones in pairing mode, but Add Bluetooth Device never shows up anything.

I also have a Logitech Performance MX mouse's bluetooth dongle. Should I use this instead?

I can't even see my headphones in the device list, let alone try to see if there is any sound coming from the PC.

Comment: Have you contacted CSR support? Does the Logitech device work? If not, there may be something wrong with the PC.

Comment: I tried the logitech but it think it's for a mouse which it is so I couldn't use it. I didn't contact CSR as they don't even seem to provide drivers on their site according to other people.

Comment: IMO, you should return the device for a refund and spend the money on a brand known for supporting their products.

Comment: Yes but I got it from aliexpress for a couple bucks and I am not sure which bluetooth dongle is better. I just bought a bluetooth adapter from the same site which I am more hopeful that it will work. Bluetooth support on Win7 also doesn't seem great tbh so it's not helping.